# How to prevent gtk redrawing the entire GtkDrawingArea?

Tags: linux, user-interface, gtk, gtk3, cairo

This is my code. I hope it can draw a circle when users press button. The circel is centered around the point where the mouse key pressed. But the program doesn't run as expected. It clears the pre-circles and draws a new circle. Are there some functions to solve this problem?

My codes:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void do_drawing(cairo_t *);

struct {
   int count;
   double coordx[100];
   double coordy[100];
} glob;

static gboolean on_draw_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr,
    gpointer user_data)
{
   do_drawing(cr);

   return FALSE;
}

static void do_drawing(cairo_t *cr)
{
   cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
   cairo_set_line_width(cr, 0.5);

   if(glob.count)
   {
    cairo_set_font_size(cr, 20);
    cairo_new_sub_path(cr);
    cairo_arc(cr, glob.coordx[glob.count-1], glob.coordy[glob.count-1], 20, 0, 2*G_PI);
    cairo_move_to(cr, glob.coordx[glob.count-1]-3, glob.coordy[glob.count-1] + 7);
    cairo_show_text(cr, "i");
    cairo_stroke(cr);
   }
}

static gboolean clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event,
    gpointer user_data)
{
   if (event->button == 1) {
      glob.coordx[glob.count] = event->x;
      glob.coordy[glob.count++] = event->y;
      gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
}

  return TRUE;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *darea;

  glob.count = 0;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), darea);

  gtk_widget_add_events(darea, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw",
        G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL);
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  g_signal_connect(darea, "button-press-event",
        G_CALLBACK(clicked), NULL);

  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 300);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Lines");

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

I know the gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget) will redraw the GtkDrawingArea entirely, So which function can replace it? I have another question: If I wan to draw on GtkDrawingArea, should I create cairo_t before drawing? How to create a cairo_t for GtkDrawingArea?

Comment: You have to be able to redraw all of the GtkDrawingArea's content. It does not keep its content around for you. I suggest that you keep a list of points around so that you can redraw all of them.

Comment: You mean I should redraw all pre circles when I draw a new circles?

Comment: Can I set the redrawing area?

Comment: @Uli Schlachter, how about gtk_widget_queue_draw_area()?

Comment: You must redraw all circles in your `on_draw_event()` function. Gtk calls that function whenever it is unsure about the content of some rectangle of the `GtkDrawingArea`. One reason why it is unsure can be that you told it to redraw some part. But there can also be external reason, e.g. the window / widget being resized.

Comment: With `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area()`, you can Gtk that some part of the widget needs redrawing. `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` does basically the same thing, but with "the whole widget needs redrawing" instead of just "this area needs redrawing".

Comment: But redrawing all circles is wasting time and resource. No other ways to solve it?@Uli Schlachter

Comment: what does rectangle in "some rectangle of the GtkDrawingArea" mean?

Comment: To your first question: I am definitely no expert in Gtk, so my honest answer is: I do not know. To your second question: With "some rectangle" I mean basically... uhm... "some area on screen"? "Some region of pixels"? Does that make it clearer?

Comment: how to use gtk_queue_draw_region()?@ Uli Schlachter

Comment: Create a region and then call the function. Perhaps `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area()` is easier to use?

Comment: I have two questions: first, how to create the region if I use gtk_queue_draw_region()? second:If I use gtk_widget_queue_draw_area() to draw a line on a circle. how to calculate the area redrawn @ Uli Schlachter?

Comment: Seems like you can create a region from a list of rectangles: https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Regions.html Also: no idea how to compute the bounding box easily, but perhaps that's also not necessary. Just redraw everything without any rectangles?

Comment: I will do as you suggest.Thanks